# Why unable to update columns in listitem using CSOM?

Tags: list, csom, list-item, updatelistitems

I am trying to perform a basic operation,updating a column in a list item of a list.Following is the code ,

```
    List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("HomePageTab"); 
    ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById(1);
    oListItem["Link Location"] = "https://www.google.com";
    oListItem.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

When i execute this code.I get following error.

> {"Column 'Link Location' does not exist. It may have been deleted by
>   another user.  /sites/ModusDev/Lists/HomePageTab"}

The issue is the column is available but still unable to update the empty column for the selected listitem.What might be the reason.

I have a url having characters more than 256 which is not accepted when entering in linklocation column. So I am trying to enter the url to link location programatically using CSOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Error reason

```
 oListItem["Link Location"] = "https://www.google.com";
```

In above code `Link Location` is the display name of your column. Use internal name instead.

## Update#1

You won't be able to enter 255+ characters using CSOM also.

Comment: Ok ,may i know how to find the internal name of the column?

Comment: Go to list settings---> click on the column----> find internal name in the end of the url in browser

Comment: I have a url generated for a azure website which exceeds 256 characters. Is there any way to optimize the URL? @atish

Comment: There is HyperLink type column. you can use it. Anyway now accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update a column `Link Location`, @Atish is correct that this is a display name. And while you try to update any item you need to refer the internal names.

SharePoint has its own logic of maintaining the internal names. Most often the spaces in the names are converted to `_x0020_`. So instead of your code try below.

```
oListItem["Link_x0020_Location"] = "https://www.google.com";
```

Comment: Doesn't have the FieldUrlValue has the 255-chars limitation, too?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldurlvalue.url.aspx says for FieldUrlValue.Url: "Its length must be equal to or less than 255 [..]"